# German jewish census records from the 19th century

Tags: germany, jewish, census-records

I have been told that some censuses of the Jewish population of German towns were conducted in the first half of the 19th century. I am wondering if there is any systematic record of these censuses (when and where they were conducted, aggregate statistics, etc.) and of the individual records so collected.

I am specifically interested in the Pfalz region.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:cGf4YjthNUwJ:www.loc.gov/rr/genealogy/bib_guid/german-immigration.pdf+&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgfIvJ9uf0AfebDY1vEmIf5XzTcUtbStQm8qEPlVfTLthos8It3nsp5_rsrhHVrj66txAED-Dhx0V_iLs90dde3UtABy58e9aBLwXm8CEotAjqpT_BMG0ahmNf9G97vEMH1VL5a&sig=AHIEtbTDWS83jO5QhqYmgr9lxr5_YyNf1g

Comment: Ezri, that list looks like a good collection of resources that document immigration; I am interested in resources that describe the population in place.

Answer (score 2):

Your description suggests that you may be referring to the 1848 Hungarian Jewish Census also known by its Latin name, "Conscriptio Judaerum 1848".

This was conducted across the Hungarian Empire but one of the fields it captured was place of birth (and Bavaria, as Bajor, was one of the options).

The website [JewishGen](http://www.jewishgen.org/databases/hungary/census1848.htm) gives a good deal of detail, including which records have been filmed.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of the 1835 census, a transcription of records from which (from Offenbach am Glan, in the western part of the modern Pfalz region) I was given by a vicar from that town.